# How well can agile pair programming work in interdisciplinary DevOps contexts?

Tags: deployment, culture, agile, software-engineering

In agile, pair programming can be performed like the following:

- two specialists of same discipline change the place before the terminal and each has a chance to code and to conceptualize/reflect;
- two specialists of different disciplines work together, but one is rather a customer and cannot code much in the target language; also the coder might not know much about the requirements which then discussed directly and coded and tested and deployed.

How is this relevant/appliable in DevOps context? (facts)

Answer (score 2):

Agile fits very well with a DevOps culture and pair programming is no exception.

The following are some examples of "pair programming" principles applied in a DevOps context:

- A pair of individuals working together on a Dockerfile for their service.
- A pairing sits together to work on defining their infrastructure as code.
- A traditional developer and an IT administrator building a [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI/CD) pipeline together.
- A specialist and tester sit together to define what the testing environment should look like.
- A specialist and a customer sitting together and working on a deployment to the customers infrastructure.